# acts_as_taggable undefined method 'each' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to use acts_as_taggable plugin to include tag functionality in my ruby on rails application. I have attached the code. I have installed the plugin and also run the migrations.I am getting the following error.

```
undefined method `each' for "value of the parameter":String
```

**Code**

**location.rb** - location table has name, tags(this is an additional field I have in the table, I added it before knowing about the plugin :), city fields

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  acts_as_tagger
end
```

**location_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @location = Location.new(params[:location])
  @location.tag_list = ["tags1","tags2"]
  if @location.save
     redirect_to(@location)
  else
     redirect_to(@profile)
  end 
end
```

**Application Trace**

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:320:in `replace'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1331:in `block in collection_accessor_methods'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2906:in `block in assign_attributes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2902:in `assign_attributes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2775:in `attributes='
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:2473:in `initialize'
/Users/felix/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:92:in `new'
/Users/felix/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:92:in `create'
```

Thanks

Comment: When do you get the above error? Where does the error appear? Is there a stack trace with the error?

Comment: I got it in the controller code, I have updated the question with the application trace

Comment: Can you please share what you ended up doing (which option from the accepted answer) to resolve the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Ruby 1.9 by any chance? The rest of this answer is prefaced on a yes. If so read on.

You may have stumbled over a 1.9 change of behavior. Strings in 1.9 no longer support `each` (i.e. they are not`Enumerable` like Ruby 1.8). But you can use `each_char` which is probably what was intended.

If this isn't your code blowing up then you could either:

- Go back to 1.8.x (Obvious)
- Hack the String class by adding a method `each` (Messy and possibly dangerous)
- Fix the gem or plugin that is causing the trouble.

There's a great article on all this [here](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, since I'm not sure what the values in params are (perhaps you can output a `params.inspect` to get them); I think the value you passed to Location.new in params[:location] is a String and it was expecting a hash of key value pairs.

Maybe you meant: `Location.new(:location => params[:location])`

Or: `Location.new(params)`

Or maybe `Location.new(params[:location])` **is correct**, but it is not a hash like it should be (this is usually done for you by the form helpers in your view code).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with acts_as_taggable complaining about an undefined each method and the problem was I had the wrong field in my view _form. I had:

```
<%= f.text_field :tags %>
```

instead of what it should be:

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `@location.tag_list = ["tags1","tags2"]`
with

`@location.tag_list = "tags1, tags2"`

also you can add tags like so

`@location.tag_list.add("tag1, tag2", parse: true)`

check [this cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) for more info